# NestedScrollView is not working

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

This is my .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.Nestedsrollview xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rushabh123453.attendancepict.Attendance">




        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_attfinal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="78"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="120sp"
                android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                android:background="@color/blue"


            />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:gravity="center"/>


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.Nestedsrollview >
```

I want to scroll whole layout using nestedscrollview but its showing error of illegal statement:host only one child.

I have tried to make each child of that into wrap_content,but this also dint work

build.gradle(app level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rushabh123453.attendancepict"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
}
```

Comment: A NestedScrollView can only have one child. Your NestedScrollView has two children.

Comment: So what can be done?

Comment: Update your layout so that the NestedScrollView only has one child instead of two.

Comment: But i want to divide the screen using weight so i cant change it,any alternative?

Comment: what you want actually? means when top layer scroll up then?

Comment: Every thing should scrollup not only the cardview should scroll

Answer (score 0):

first of all use  `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`.

and second change in your xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_attfinal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="78"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="120sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

okay now try this..

Updated Build Gradle

replace this :-

```
   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143379/discussion-on-answer-by-andie-nestedscrollview-is-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

```
try, Put NestedScrollView in Main Linear layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

              <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_attfinal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="78"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="120sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/product_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you added setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) fro recycler view like that : -    RecyclerView bestRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.product_list); bestRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);